# MediaElement can't play large videos in Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to create a mediaplayer that can play customize format

I encrypt the videos with Aes and now i want to first decrypt it and play .
Everything looks good, there is no error, but my videos doesnt play

Here is the intersting point that the output file (from decryption) is ok, the only way to run video is it need to copy to Main storage to play with other media player!!

But my mediaplayer cant play it from app directory , it means i should manuelly copy it to default storage to play

My decryption

```
public void FileDecrypt(Stream encryptedFileStream, byte[] key, byte[] iv, string path)
 {
     var bytes = new byte[encryptedFileStream.Length];
     var filestreamoutput = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
     var AES = Aes.Create();
     AES.Key = key;
     AES.IV = iv;
     AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
     AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

     var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedFileStream, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
     //var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

     int data;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     try
     {
         while ((data = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != -1)
         {
             if (data != 1024)
             {
                 byte[] buffertemp = new byte[data];
                 filestreamoutput.Write(buffertemp, 0, data);
                 //filestreamoutput.Flush();
                 filestreamoutput.Close();
                 GC.Collect();
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 filestreamoutput.Write(buffer, 0, data);
                 //filestreamoutput.Flush();
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         filestreamoutput.Close();
     }



     return;
 }
```

And my play methoud

```
var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
            if (file == null)
            {
                return;
            }
       
          var  path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "a.mp4");
            //File.WriteAllBytes(path,File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullPath));
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

            var key = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("94a9gTIrrE9ke9nSgLZwOPRP$vY!I5qu");
            var iv = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("E%Sdxf4w1qdgEF1&");
            FileDecrypt(stream, key, iv, path);
this.MediaElement.Source = path;
            this.MediaElement.Play();
`
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: is your problem decrypting the file, or playing it afterwards?  All the code you posted has to do with decryption, not playback.

Comment: My problem is the mediaplayer cant play large videos, but for small videos everything is ok

Comment: then why did you post a bunch of unrelated code?  How large is this file?  Do you get an error or exception when you try to play it?  What specifically happens?

Comment: Look there is no any error , the above code for small videos(like10 mg) is ok but for large videos (like500 mg) its not ok,  code run but in the end, player does not play the video, idont know where is my problem , its becouse of mediaplayer or beacuse of  decryption

Comment: file a [bug report](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues)

Comment: Did you try to test it on the different devices?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code may be the root cause :

```
this.MediaElement.Source = path;
```

Indeed, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement#play-local-media), it says:

> In code, please use MediaSource.FromResource() and
> MediaSource.FromFile() respectively.

I have written a series of articles about the `MediaElement`, where I use `MediaSource.FromUri()` to play streaming audio. If you are interested, you can start from [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/10-play-music-with-mediaelement).